# Different forms of compactness and their relation

Tags: gn.general-topology, reference-request

Given a topological space X one can define several notion of compactness:

X is **compact** if every open cover has a finite subcover.

X is **sequentially compact** if every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

X is **limit point compact** (or Bolzano-Weierstrass) if every infinite set has an accumulation point.

X is **countably compact** if every countable open cover has a finite subcover.

X is **σ-compact** if it is the union of countably many compact subspaces.

X is **pseudocompact** if its if its image under any continuous function to $\mathbb{R}$ is 
bounded.

X is **paracompact** if every open cover admits an open locally finite refinement (i.e. every point of X has a neighborhood small enough to intersect only finitely many members of the cover).

X is **metacompact** if every open cover admits a point finite open refinement (i.e. if every point of X is in only finitely many members of the refinement).

X is **orthocompact** if every open cover has an interior preserving open refinement (i.e. given an open cover there is a open subcover such that at any point, the intersection of all open sets in the subcover containing that point is also open).

X is **mesocompact** if every open cover has a compact-finite open refinement (i.e. given any open cover, we can find an open refinement such that every compact set is contained in finitely many members of the refinement).

So, there are quite a few notions of compactness (there are surely more than those I quoted up here). The question is: where are these definitions systematically studied? What I'm interested in particular is knowing when does one imply the other, when does it not (examples), &c.

I can fully answer the question for the first three notions:

Compact and first-countable --> Sequentially compact.

Sequentially compact and second-countable --> Compact.

Sequentially compact --> Limit-point compact.

Limit point compact, first-countable and $T_1$ --> Sequentially compact.

but I'm absolutely ignorant about the other cases. Has this been systematically studied somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: You will certainly find interesting *Counterexamples in topology* by L.A.Steen and J.A.Seebach, Jr.

Comment: You should get Munkres' First Course in Topology and read it if you have not done already. This is not the question for Mathoverflow. It is actually a fair general topology homework assignment for a solid undergraduate student.

Comment: Surely so for some of the notions (especially the implications I stated at the end of the post), but most of them are not even defined in Munkres book.

Comment: But why bother learning any one of these notions unless you actually need it?

Comment: I think all but the last three ones are either important or natural to formulate, so it is interesting per se to ask oneself what kind of relationship do they bear.

Comment: Years ago I spent some time thinking about ultrafilters. Recall that a _filter_ on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that if $A,B \subseteq X$ are in the filter, so is $A\cap B$, and if $A\supseteq B \supseteq X$ and $A$ is in the filter, then so is $B$. A filter is _proper_ if it does not contain the empty set, and an _ultrafilter_ is a maximal proper filter. Given a filter on $X$ and a topological space $Y$, a _limit_ of a function $f : X\to Y$ is a point $y\in Y$ such that every open containing $y$ pulls back to an element of the filter. For example, letting (continued)

Comment: (continuation) $X = \mathbb N$ and picking the _cofinite filter_ (a subset of $\mathbb N$ is in the filter if its complement is finite) returns the usual Cauchy definition of the limit of a sequence. If $Y$ is compact (and Hausdorff) and we pick an ultrafilter on $X$, then every function has a unique limit (necessarily, if the ultrafilter contains the cofinite filter, to an accumulation point). On the other hand, my adviser for the project gave an example of a sequence in $[0,1]$ and an ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$ so that no convergent (in the cofinite filter) subsequence pulled (continued)

Comment: (continuation) back to an element of the ultrafilter. The reason I bring this up is that I think it illustrates some big differences between sequential and limit-point compactness. The reason I leave it as an extended comment is that it really is not an answer to your question.  (The correct answer to your question being the one Pietro Majer has already given, namely that _Counterexamples in topology_ is an excellent book, and almost certainly contains what you're looking for.)

Comment: For me it seems that although it is, up to some extent, a basic general topology question, it is a very good question. Munkres' book doesn't provide you with all the definitions given by Bruno, let alone all their interrelations. One comes across these definitions every now and then, and their relations and relative properties can be useful. The counter examples book can give you some intuition and place to start with but the question won't be answered completely there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have Munkres' book.  So I don't know what is done there.  You should probably consult the "Counterexamples in Topology" as mentioned above.
My favourite book for questions of this type is "General Topology" by Ryszard Engelking.
It has a diagram in the back with interrelations between different properties of topological spaces.  It has all the notions you are interested in, except the last two.  Local compactness and various additional versions of paracompactness are also discussed in the book.
I assume, but haven't checked in every case, that the relations in the diagram are proved in the book.
The book also contains plenty of examples, showing that certain implications do not hold, sometimes in the form of exercises with hints.